# Getting MSVC to approximate the performace of clang

Tags: c, performance, visual-c++, random

I am trying to get decent performance out of MSVC for this code. My naive benchmark shows clang's executable run time is about 10% of the MSVC's runtime. GCC is between the two and is typically about 25% of MSVC.  Is it possible to trick MSVC into producing better assembly?  I've looked at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zjDAgr) but my experiments haven't made much difference. For background, this is the core block of the Philox4x32 random number generator.

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct array2x32 {
  uint32_t v[2];
};
struct array4x32 {
  uint32_t v[4];
};


struct array4x32 round4x32(struct array4x32 ctr, struct array2x32 key) {
  uint32_t hi0, hi1, lo0, lo1;
  uint64_t product;
  product = 0x00000000D2511F53ULL * (uint64_t)ctr.v[0];
  lo0 = (uint32_t)product;
  hi0 = ((uint32_t)(product>>32)) ^ ctr.v[3] ^ key.v[1];
  product = 0x00000000CD9E8D57ULL * (uint64_t)ctr.v[2];
  lo1 = (uint32_t)product;
  hi1 = ((uint32_t)(product>>32)) ^ ctr.v[1] ^ key.v[0];
  struct array4x32 out = {{hi1, lo1, hi0, lo0}};
  return out;
}

#define N 1000000000
int main(){
      struct array4x32 ctr = {{0, 0, 0, 0}};
  struct array2x32 key = {{0, 0xDEADBEAF}};
  struct array4x32 out;
  uint64_t count = 0, sum = 0;
  int i, j;
  clock_t begin = clock();
  for (i = 0; i < N / 4UL; i++) {
    ctr.v[0]++;
    out = round4x32(ctr, key);
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      sum += out.v[j];
      count++;
    }
  }
  clock_t end = clock();
  double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("%0.10f", time_spent);
  printf("0x%" PRIx64 "\ncount: %" PRIu64 "\n", sum, count);
  printf("%" PRIu64 " randoms per second\n",
         (uint64_t)((N / time_spent) / 1000000 * 1000000));
}
```

Comment: For me both Clang v8.0 and GCC v8.1 are pretty close, and GCC has a slight edge (3.65bln vs 3.37bln), but MSVC (latest one , v19.22) is literally more than order of magnitude slower (278mln). Windows 10, x64, 1809.

Comment: I reran and now get similar timings as you.  I mostly follow the logic of the assembly that is on Compiler Explorer.  I am amazed that clang/GCC are ~10x faster. I *guess* (beyond my area) that the differences are due to the mix of instructions rather than the number, since the number of instructions only differs by a few.

Comment: I would suggest you should report this example to MSVC compiler team. In VS IDE Help -> Send Feedback -> Report Problem

Comment: And I've tried to annotate round4x32() with __fastcall and __forceinline, but it didn't help

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks.  I've reported it.  I didn't know that feature was there.  I wonder how likely I am to get a response...